# help with ajax jquery css thing

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

Could someone have a quick glance at this code and let me know where I'm going wrong.

On the blur event, the `.textok` class loads fine but, the `.textbad` class does not.

```
<style>
   .textok {
color:#0F0;
background-color:#093;
};
.textbad {
color:#F00;
background-color:#900;
 };
  </style>

 <script>

$("#name").blur(function()
{
$.post("logval.php?type=name",{ name:$('#name').val() } ,function(data)
    {
      if(data=='noname') //if no username
      {
      $("#usererror").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() //start fading the messagebox
            {
              //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
              $("#usererror").html('Name Accepted      ').addClass("textbad").fadeTo(900,1);
              $("#tic").attr("src","tic.gif").fadeTo(900,1);
            });
      } else 
      {
      $("#usererror").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() //start fading the messagebox
            {
              //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
              $("#usererror").html('Name Accepted  ').addClass("textok").fadeTo(900,1);
              $("#tic").attr("src","tic.gif").fadeTo(900,1);
            });
      }
    });
})




     </script>
```

Comment: off-topic, but just as a matter of good practice, I would always recommend using six-digit hex codes for colour references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't put semicolons after closing braces in CSS:

```
.textok {
    color:#0F0;
    background-color:#093;
} /* No semicolon here! */
```

It's those semicolons that are preventing your CSS from being understood.